# How to add a normal background in a parallax website

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put an overall background image in this website but when I type the code in it does not appear, I think this is because of the parallax image, is there a way to have the background image appear. I think that the background image is behind everything else maybe a way to bring it forward?

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Croydon Cycles</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="parallax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body >

    <div class="title">
        <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Croydon Cycles" align="center">
    </div>
    <div class="menu">

        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>


<div class="container">



    <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-z-index="1">
        <div class="b1">
            <a href="shop.html">

                <input type="button" class="button" value="view all bikes" >
            </a>
        </div>




    </div>
    <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
            all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
            road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
            Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
            however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>


</div>


<div class="profiles">

        <p id="Header-1">Here are some of the members of Croydon Cycles:</p>

    <div class="pic-1">
        <img src="images/profile-1.jpg" alt="Proffesional biker"  height="280px" width="420px">
        <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
                all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
                road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
                Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
                however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>
    </div>



    <div class="pic-2">
    <img src="images/profile-2.jpg" alt="Proffesional biker"  height="280px" width="420px">
    <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
            all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
            road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
            Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
            however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    margin: 2.5%;
    padding:0;
}
.title {
    text-align: center;
}
.container {

    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    font-size: 24px;
    object-fit: cover;

}

.parallax {
    background: url('images/background-1.jpeg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;


}

.b1{
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 92%;
    left: 42.5%;
}

.pic-1{
    height:280px; 
    width:420px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 100px;
}


.pic-2{
    height:280px; 
    width:420px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 100px;  

}

#Header-1 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 35px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
}

ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 100px;


}

ul li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    padding:0px 20px;

}



#nav {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add z-index in your CSS to change order:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
.parallax {
    background: url('images/background-1.jpeg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

background for body will be considered on top if z-index of it is greater than z-index of parallax background.

Comment: I added the z-index to the background in CSS, this did not fix it so I tried doing it in the HTML file by adding <body background="background.jpg" z-index=1> this also did not add the background to the website.

Comment: Fix the URL in body CSS for background, add proper URL just like in parallax

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.